# Implement {duplicate}, {closed} etc. tags as UI elements, rather than appending text

Tags: feature-request, tags, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

At this point, I am very much used to closed/duplicate questions being marked with `[closed]` or `[duplicate]` text in their title:

> [image]

> [image]

But what exactly is stopping us from implementing it as an actual separate UI element, like a pill, or a badge?

> [image]

*I hope, it is obvious that I'm not proposing this or any other particular design, that's just an example.*

Comment: I actually think this is a good idea - I've more than once skimmed over the [text] and it would be nice to have the whole thing more obvious

Comment: IMO, the title in the question can look whatever it is right now. It should be fairly obvious the question is closed with the really big closure notification there. However, in a question list it's harder to see it. It would be helpful if it was on the side. Similar to how we have other information about a question, including a marker for deleted questions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB7h0.png The part of the question card is what shows information about the post. It's where the closed status seems to belong to.

Comment: Clickbait title idea: “Make distinct from normal title text the marker that a question is a”

Comment: @user3840170 Ah, I see now what you mean :) I did something similar

Comment: I thought I'd try manually appending "[duplicate]" to a title in the sandbox is possible.  Turns out, it's not, but you can append "[duplicatе]" which looks virtually identical (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/3122/522)).  It uses unicode "е", which looks almost identical to "e".

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Sounds like this deserves a separate `bug` question